# Matching timestamped data to closest time in another dataset leads to different amount of rows

Tags: r, timestamp, data.table

I have a timestamp in one data frame that I am trying to match to the closest timestamp in a second dataframe, for the purpose of extracting data from the second dataframe.

Earlier I found that I can try `data.tables` rolling join using the `nearest` option:

```
library(data.table) # v1.9.6+

setDT(reference)[data, refvalue, roll = "nearest", on = "datetime"]
# [1] 5 7 7 8
```

However, this results in a list that is 2 rows longer than the data file.
Is this because the time stamps of 2 observations were equally close to 2 time stamps (one earlier, one later)?

Is there an option for when the time of an observation is in the middle of 2 time stamps? Is there a function to choose for one of the 2 time stamps? Or can you find out for which observation there are two possible time stamps?

If I merge the list with the data, the 2 last observations from the list are unused, I figured this changes my data.

Thank You!

Comment: try the `mult = "first"` argument (it defaults to "all")

Comment: @docendodiscimus `roll=` should return one result per row of `i` and not need `mult=`..? I guess the OP needs to show a real example (which could be as small as a two row `reference` and a one row `data`, maybe).

Comment: @Frank, I agree that a minimal example would be very useful.